# My URL doesn't work, but Route 53 test says NOERROR

Tags: dns, amazon-aws, amazon-ec2, route53

I've done a migration for my wordpress site from MediaTemple to AWS.

I've got my Route 53 to point to the LoadBalancer that points my EC2 with the properly approved certificate.

I created a Hosted Zone, and created an "A record" that aliases the load balancer.

Everything should naturally work. And when I try the "Test Record Set" from Route 53 for my "A record", it gives me NOERROR. Response is returned from proper IP.

But when I try the same URL from my Google Chrome, it gives me ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on Normal mode, or DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on incognito mode.

Why is that so? Some people say that I have to max 72 hours, and then it will fix itself. Is that true?